# Using python interactive mode with conEmu.

Tags: python, conemu

i could not find an answer to this question online, so i'm hoping y'all can help.
I installed conEmu to have a terminal for easier access. I was using python interactive Mode in Windows cmd by just typing 'python', but in conEmu, it seems to be waiting for a file name instead of just starting a blank interactive mode.
Is there a way i can fix this, or do i need to stick with Windows cmd? Thank you. 
Latest updates on all software.

Comment: The "it seems to be waiting for a file name instead of just starting a blank interactive mode" is unclear statement. Describe what are you doing, where, and what you get as result. Show screenshots, denote used versions.

Comment: Thank you for getting back. It was one of the features, i apparently turned off when installing git bash. I have made changes. Thank you.